# Error Code 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint for my tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to write a script for SQL for adding 2 tables and adding another table that references both tables through a foreign key. I keep getting an error from the 'Enrolls' table. It says foreign key cannot be create.

Here are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homework7`.`Section` (
  `CourseNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `SectionNo` INT NOT NULL,
  `Instructor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CourseNo`, `SectionNo`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNo`) REFERENCES Course(`CourseNo`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homework7`.`Student` (
  `SSN` INT NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Street` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `State` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  `Zip` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`));
```

Here's the one I'm having trouble with.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homework7`.`Enrolls` (
  `SSN` INT NOT NULL,
  `CourseNo` Int NOT NULL,
  `SectionNo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`, `SectionNo`, `CourseNo`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`SSN`) REFERENCES Student(`SSN`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNo`) REFERENCES Section(`CourseNo`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`SectionNo`) REFERENCES Section(`SectionNo`));
```

Also the schema is here.
[http://imgur.com/a/fTg5O](https://imgur.com/a/fTg5O)

So should 
Enrolls (CourseNo) reference Course (CourseNo) or Section (CourseNo)?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNo`) REFERENCES Section(`CourseNo`)`.  I think you want the reference to `Course`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the schema, so a foreign key can't point to a foreign key?

Comment: In general, foreign keys should refer to primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

foreign key must be primary key of other table so for the trouble portion u can use  Course(`CourseNo`) instead of Section(CourseNo) and liff also mention that

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homework7`.`Enrolls` (
  `SSN` INT NOT NULL,
  `CourseNo` Int NOT NULL,
  `SectionNo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`, `SectionNo`, `CourseNo`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`SSN`) REFERENCES Student(`SSN`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNo`) REFERENCES Course(`CourseNo`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`SectionNo`) REFERENCES Section(`SectionNo`));
```

Comment: Hmm I see, but why couldn't you reference Section primary key instead? Is it because it references Course's?

Comment: @DarkRain you could reference the PK of Section, but that is not what you are doing; you are referencing **parts of** its PK. _Also, you can reference non-PK fields as long as there is an index on them; though in practice it is almost always a bad idea._

Comment: @Uueerdo What do you mean part of it's PK?

Comment: @DarkRain Section's PK is `(CourseNo, SectionNo)`, not the fields individually as your references were attempting to reference them. It is possible the reference to `Section(CourseNo)` was actually accepted since the field begins an index; but with no index in Section beginning with SectionNo, that reference was definitely rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNo`, `SectionNo`) REFERENCES Section(`CourseNo`, `SectionNo`)
```

Foreign keys must reference fields indexed in the table referenced.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!